# Racket mutable variables

Tags: variables, scheme, racket, mutable

I am new to racket and have run into an instance where I need a mutable numeric variable

Below is a function that works thru a string of bits (101011....) and if it encounters a 1 alters a numeric variable named "value" and if it encounters a 0 has to alter that same variable "value". So when we get to the end of a string we should end up with a total for "value".

```
(define (implode bstr value)
        (for ([c (string-length bstr)])
           (display (string-ref bstr c))
      (if (eqv? (string-ref bstr c) #\1) (displayln (+ (/ value 3) 17))
          (displayln (/ value 3)))))
```

How without a mtauble variable do I have this variable change as the prgram is running please ?

Comment: Who says you need mutability for this? Hint: you can do it recursively instead of iteratively.

Comment: Ok I'm game would you have an example please ?

Answer (score 7):

Racket supports mutation.  For example:

```
#lang racket

;; count-whales: (listof string) -> number
;; Returns a count of the number of whales in lst.
(define (count-whales lst)
  (define c 0)
  (for ([thing lst])
    (when (equal? thing "shamu")
      (set! c (add1 c))))
  c)

;; Example:
(count-whales '("shamu" "donald duck" "shamu"))
```

You're probably used to seeing loops this way, where mutation allows us to record some running value.  There's no obstacle to writing with mutation.  But that being said, the above function is not idiomatic Racket.  A Racketeer will instead use a loop that can **accumulate** a value, rather than use mutation.

Here's what the above function looks like when written with an accumulator:

```
#lang racket

;; count-whales: (listof string) -> number
;; Returns a count of the number of whales in lst.
(define (count-whales lst)
  (for/fold ([c 0])
            ([thing lst])
    (if (equal? thing "shamu")
        (add1 c)
        c)))

;; Example:
(count-whales '("shamu" "donald duck" "shamu"))
```

Answer (score 6):

As has been suggested, this problem can be easily solved using recursion, without using mutable variables. That's the preferred way to write procedures in Scheme:

```
(define (implode bstr value)
  (let loop ((value value)
             (lst (string->list bstr)))
    (cond ((null? lst)
           value)
          ((char=? (car lst) #\1)
           (loop (+ (/ value 3) 17) (cdr lst)))
          ((char=? (car lst) #\0)
           (loop (/ value 3) (cdr lst)))
          (else (error "unexpected char" (car lst))))))
```

Comment: Extraordinary -It works well - Thanks and now to figure out what you did

Comment: @user1907316 glad to hear that! if this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what is the goal of the `implode` function, but yes, you definitely don't need to use mutation.  Racket is a highlevel language that has tail call elimination which means that a loop via a local function as done in Óscar's example is something that the compiler will later turn into efficient code that uses mutation or whatever is needed.

But more than that, it would be good to show how to write Racket code that is more concise and perhaps closer to the mental model of mutation.  The main ingredient here is [`for/fold`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._for/fold%29%29), which is doing a "for loop" but uses a "state variable" throughout the loop.  The "state" here is quoted because it's not really there -- it's actually a macro that expands to a similar kind of loop as in Óscar's example.  I also improved other parts of the code in a few minor but useful-to-know ways: you can iterate over a string directly, no need for an index; the `in-string` is not really needed there, but it makes the kind of iteration more explicit, makes it faster, and will throw an error if `bstr` is not a string; you can use `case` to check the character you're on; and as long as you're using that, it's better to throw an error if a character is neither "0" nor "1".

Here's how it looks like:

```
(define (implode bstr)
  (for/fold ([value 0]) ([c (in-string bstr)])
    (case c
      [(#\0) (+ (/ value 3) 17)]
      [(#\1) (/ value 3)]
      [else (error 'implode "bad character: ~e" c)])))
```

Still, this produces some weird results, but again, I'm not sure what this function is supposed to do...